# Unable to install libraries with pip due to outdated BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The command

```
pip install pyteaser
```

produces this error:

```
Collecting pyteaser
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/7a/310592c6e7998440e56a8650446ecf3ded076431415c60f0f3b946b54462/pyteaser-2.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pyteaser) (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /home/abhishek/PycharmProjects/learning-python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyteaser) (4.4.2)
Collecting cssselect (from pyteaser)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/d4/3b5c17f00cce85b9a1e6f91096e1cc8e8ede2e1be8e96b87ce1ed09e92c5/cssselect-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jieba (from pyteaser)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/c8/e0785494690876adbb5ac364eb148a240b738a614d7b39bf8dba8a7ad066/jieba-0.41.tar.gz
Collecting beautifulsoup (from pyteaser)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/f2/6c9f2f3e696ee6a1fb0e4d7850617e224ed2b0b1e872110abffeca2a09d4/BeautifulSoup-3.2.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging/beautifulsoup/setup.py", line 3
        "You're trying to run a very old release of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work."<>"Please use Beautiful Soup 4, available through the pip package 'beautifulsoup4'."
                                                                                                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging/beautifulsoup/
```

And the command

```
pip install pytldr
```

reports this error:

```
pip install pytldr
Collecting pytldr
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/09/02ed27061159e5f6d35abad4ec9ef3cac8e220093d61a2f7a42f53c9cb22/PyTLDR-0.1.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.0 in /home/abhishek/PycharmProjects/learning-python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytldr) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nltk>=3.0.0 in /home/abhishek/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytldr) (3.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.13.2 in /home/abhishek/PycharmProjects/learning-python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytldr) (1.4.1)
Collecting scikit-learn>=0.15.2 (from pytldr)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/48/e9fa9e252abcd1447eff6f9257636af31758a6e46fd5ce5d3c879f6907cb/scikit_learn-0.22.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting goose-extractor>=1.0.25 (from pytldr)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/f3/2e89688e4e1d8786e542ea460431f24f1392d885e60303dc20d476a96424/goose-extractor-1.0.25.tar.gz
Collecting networkx>=1.9.1 (from pytldr)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/8f/dd6a8e85946def36e4f2c69c84219af0fa5e832b018c970e92f2ad337e45/networkx-2.4-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/abhishek/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nltk>=3.0.0->pytldr) (1.12.0)
Collecting joblib>=0.11 (from scikit-learn>=0.15.2->pytldr)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/5c/cf6a2b65a321c4a209efcdf64c2689efae2cb62661f8f6f4bb28547cf1bf/joblib-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from goose-extractor>=1.0.25->pytldr) (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /home/abhishek/PycharmProjects/learning-python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from goose-extractor>=1.0.25->pytldr) (4.4.2)
Collecting cssselect (from goose-extractor>=1.0.25->pytldr)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/d4/3b5c17f00cce85b9a1e6f91096e1cc8e8ede2e1be8e96b87ce1ed09e92c5/cssselect-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jieba (from goose-extractor>=1.0.25->pytldr)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/c8/e0785494690876adbb5ac364eb148a240b738a614d7b39bf8dba8a7ad066/jieba-0.41.tar.gz
Collecting beautifulsoup (from goose-extractor>=1.0.25->pytldr)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/f2/6c9f2f3e696ee6a1fb0e4d7850617e224ed2b0b1e872110abffeca2a09d4/BeautifulSoup-3.2.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9oa07p4e/beautifulsoup/setup.py", line 3
        "You're trying to run a very old release of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work."<>"Please use Beautiful Soup 4, available through the pip package 'beautifulsoup4'."
                                                                                                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-9oa07p4e/beautifulsoup/
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

**EDIT:**

After executing the command for *BeautifulSoup*

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

the response is:

```
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /home/abhishek/PycharmProjects/learning-python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (4.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.2 in /home/abhishek/PycharmProjects/learning-python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (1.9.5)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Comment: What's the problem? You have a very specific error message that tells you how to resolve your problem. Did you try following the instructions?

Comment: Execute `pip install beautifulsoup4` followed by `pip install pyteaser` and `pip install pytldr`

Comment: Yes, and it said, "Already satisfied".

Comment: @PMende: those specific instructions would apply to the *library that uses BeautifulSoup*, not to the code the OP is using.

Comment: Check out the solution provided here: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/61509808>, it could help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the library is not (yet) ready for Python3, as you can see [here](https://github.com/jaijuneja/PyTLDR/issues/3#issuecomment-507253842) in a comment on an issue of this library. And that is the source of your problem. As you can see, there are no issues if you install the library for Python2.7:

```sh
$ sudo apt install python-pip  # or https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/
$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
$ python -m pip install pytldr
Successfully installed Pillow-6.2.2 beautifulsoup-3.2.2 cssselect-1.1.0 decorator-4.4.2 goose-extractor-1.0.25 jieba-0.42.1 lxml-4.5.0 networkx-2.2 nltk-3.4.5 numpy-1.16.6 pytldr-0.1.4 scikit-learn-0.20.4 scipy-1.2.3 singledispatch-3.4.0.3 six-1.14.0
```

Here, you can see that everything worked, because **beautifulsoup-3.2.2** version was installed. Trying the same command for Python3 leads to the error you're posted:

```sh
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
$ python3 -m pip install pytldr
Collecting beautifulsoup
  Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.2.tar.gz (32 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-12aluvvq/beautifulsoup/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-12aluvvq/beautifulsoup/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-12aluvvq/beautifulsoup/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-12aluvvq/beautifulsoup/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-12aluvvq/beautifulsoup/setup.py", line 3
        "You're trying to run a very old release of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work."<>"Please use Beautiful Soup 4, available through the pip package 'beautifulsoup4'."
                                                                                                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

The error message is very clear:

> You're trying to run a very old release of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work. Please use Beautiful Soup 4, available through the pip package 'beautifulsoup4'.

Simply installing *BeautifulSoup4* is not solving the problem, because the library still uses code for *BeautifulSoup3*. That's a dependency of the *pytldr* package.

Now you have several options, maybe more:

1. Do not use this library.
2. Use Python2 (But [it's the year 2020](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/#update)).
3. There is already [an open pull request](https://github.com/jaijuneja/PyTLDR/pull/2) that offers code that allegedly has updated the library to be compliant with Python3. You can build the library from source with code provided there (no guarantee that this will work) or wait until the pull request was approved (or write to the author).
4. [Go through the forks](https://github.com/jaijuneja/PyTLDR/network/members) and see if anyone has already got the library up and running for Python3.
5. Try to update the library yourself and maybe with the help of [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html).

You can apparently also install [this fork](https://github.com/vinodnimbalkar/PyTLDR) directly instead of step 3. Of course, this fork may be out-of-date at some point, or it may be modified in such a way that it is no longer usable. There is also the option of [installing a specific commit](https://github.com/vinodnimbalkar/PyTLDR). But also no guarantee that this will work.

Comment: None of the pyteaser forks that I looked at work, because none remove the dependency.

Comment: Yes, because of that I added the sentence: "But also no guarantee that this will work." [Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60886282/2648551) is closer to the underlying problem and already gives a good explanation (+1) why there are still problems.

Answer (score 1):

The pyteaser and goose-extractor libraries simply use the *BeautifulSoup 3* library, which uses a *different name* from BeautifulSoup 4. You can't just install BeautifulSoup 4, because *pyteaser* and *goose-extractor* need to be updated to use the newer BeautifulSoup library. That's going to be more work, because those 2 projects are not compatible with Python 3 *either*.

You are basically stuck with Python 2 for these projects unless you are willing to do all the upgrade work yourself or put your trust in incomplete forks:

- Unfortunately, even the forks that purport to make pyteaser Python 3 compatible have left in the wrong dependency. The project doesn't actually even import BeautifulSoup anywhere, so you'd have to clone one of the Python 3 forks ([like this one](https://github.com/alanbuxton/PyTeaserPython3)) and remove the [`beautifulsoup` entry from the `install_requires` line](https://github.com/alanbuxton/PyTeaserPython3/blob/master/setup.py#L12).
- For PyTLDR, [this fork](https://github.com/vinodnimbalkar/PyTLDR) can be installed on Python 3:

  ```
  pip install git+https://github.com/vinodnimbalkar/PyTLDR.git#egg=pytldr
  ```

  It dropped goose altogether.

  Your mileage may vary, however, since the conversion looks, to me, somewhat haphazard. For Unicode text (the default in Python 3), [normalization will never take place](https://github.com/vinodnimbalkar/PyTLDR/blob/5b8841ca59af335e31565bde999fc7863f0f3bc7/pytldr/nlp/preprocess.py#L5-L11) (both the `if` and `elif` branches test for the same condition now), for example. And while it removed the `goose-extractor` *dependency*, the [code still tries to import it if you referenced it](https://github.com/vinodnimbalkar/PyTLDR/blob/5b8841ca59af335e31565bde999fc7863f0f3bc7/pytldr/nlp/preprocess.py#L18-L22), which won't work either.

If you wanted to use *goose-extractor* directly, you can replace with [`goose3`](https://pypi.org/project/goose3/). Note that this also changed the module name, to `goose3` (so the PyTLDR fork above could perhaps be fixed by changing the imported module name).