# Beautifulsoup4 not installing for pipenv

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, pipenv

I wanted to install beautifulsoup4 with pipenv, i tried with cmd as well as pycharm, both gives this error

## ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (0d3df0)…
Installing initially failed dependencies…

An error occurred while installing beautifulsoup==3.2.2 --hash=sha256:a04169602bff6e3138b1259dbbf491f5a27f9499dea9a8fbafd48843f9d89970 --hash=sha256:d31413d71f6ca027ff6b06c891b62ee8ff48267ccd969f881d810e5d1fe49565! Will try again.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1874, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       keep_outdated=keep_outdated
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1253, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 859, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       retry_list, procs, failed_deps_queue, requirements_dir, **install_kwargs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 763, in batch_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, not blocking, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Collecting beautifulsoup==3.2.2', '  Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.2.tar.gz (32 kB)']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:', '     command: \'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\.virtualenvs\\craigs--1kFvJc3\\Scripts\\python.exe\' -c \'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = \'"\'"\'C:\\\\Users\\\\xxxx\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\pip-install-icq1fnsg\\\\beautifulsoup\\\\setup.py\'"\'"\'; __file__=\'"\'"\'C:\\\\Users\\\\xxxxx\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\pip-install-icq1fnsg\\\\beautifulsoup\\\\setup.py\'"\'"\';f=getattr(tokenize, \'"\'"\'open\'"\'"\', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace(\'"\'"\'\\r\\n\'"\'"\', \'"\'"\'\\n\'"\'"\');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, \'"\'"\'exec\'"\'"\'))\' egg_info --egg-base \'C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-icq1fnsg\\beautifulsoup\\pip-egg-info\'', '         cwd: C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-icq1fnsg\\beautifulsoup\\', '    Complete output (6 lines):', '    Traceback (most recent call last):', '      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>', '      File "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-icq1fnsg\\beautifulsoup\\setup.py", line 3', '        "You\'re trying to run a very old release of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work."<>"Please use Beautiful Soup 4, available through the pip package \'beautifulsoup4\'."', '                                                                                                        ^', '    SyntaxError: invalid syntax', '    ----------------------------------------', 'ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.']
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

**1.** Open **PyCharm**.

**2.** go to `File -> settings -> Project:test(test means your project name) -> select project interpretor -> click add button`

[image]

**3.** after clicking add button and **search** `beautifulsoup4` then **install** it.