# ImportError: cannot import name 'serve' from 'waitress'

Tags: python, pycharm, waitress

```
from waitress import serve              # error line 
import app                              # python file where flask code is written
serve(app.app,port=8000,thread=55)
```

1. Python version : 3.7
2. waitress version : try with 1.4.1 and 1.3.0*

**Stack Trace**

```
C:\Users\ashish.kamble\ModelDeployment\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/ashish.kamble/PycharmProjects/ModelDeployment/waitress.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ashish.kamble/PycharmProjects/ModelDeployment/waitress.py", line 1, in <module>
    from waitress import serve
  File "C:\Users\ashish.kamble\PycharmProjects\ModelDeployment\waitress.py", line 1, in <module>
    from waitress import serve
ImportError: cannot import name 'serve' from 'waitress' (C:\Users\ashish.kamble\PycharmProjects\ModelDeployment\waitress.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Are sure you installed it correctly

Comment: If you have python 2 and python 3 you should use pip3 to install your packages

Comment: yes installed with pip3 only...

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace

Comment: @CodeYard Stack trace added ..please check

Comment: When you use pycharm follow these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61509808/11383441) to install libraries.

Comment: How did you install waitress

Comment: @Kalana i used same procedure as you have mention !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Error occurred because of your file name is `waitress.py`.

When you run your code your `waitress` keyword work as an object of your file. There for if you want to get rid of from that error **rename your python file** into which not represent your libraries.

**Addition** -: It is better to install libraries using Pycharm project interpreter. Follow these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61509808/11383441) to install libraries using interpreter.